# se agotó el tamaño de memoria permitido

Tags: php, mvc

Intentado solucionar errores en mi **MVC** he llegado a esto y no se por que, he probado con `ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');` y sigue la cosa igual, ¿que podría hacer? EL error es este:

> Error fatal : se agotó el tamaño de memoria permitido de 536870912
> bytes (intentó asignar 4096 bytes)

Tengo mi archivo Libraries/Core donde tengo my mysql.php

```
class Mysql extends Conexion {

private $conexion;
private $strquery;
private $arrvalues;

function __construct()
{
    $this->conexion = new Conexion();
    $this->conexion = $this->conexion->conect();
}

  //devuelve todos los registros
  public function select_all(string $query) {
    $this ->strquery = $query;
    $result = $this ->conexion->prepare($this->strquery);
    $result->execute();
    $data = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $data;
}
}
```

mi **autoload.php**

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class){
    // var_dump($class) ;
    if(file_exists("Libraries/".'Core/'.$class.".php")){
        require_once("Libraries/".'Core/'.$class.".php");
    }
});
```

A parte tengo mi carpeta aparte de Models y hago mis consultas
**Models/clientesModel.php**

```
class clientesModel extends Mysql {

 public $model;
 public function __construct()
{
    $this->model = new clientesModel();
    parent::__construct();
}

 public function getClients()
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM clientes";
    $viewClient = $this->select_all($sql);
    return $viewClient;
}
}
```

y mi controlador en otra carperta aparte donde llama a la funcion del modelo
**Controllers/Clientes.php**

```
class Clientes extends Controllers
{

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

public function home()
{
    // $data['page_id'] = 1;
    $data['tag_page'] = "GymArt";
    $data['page_title'] = "Clientes";
    // $data["clientes"] =$this->verUsuarios();

    $this->views->getView($this, "clientes", $data);
}

public function verUsuarios()
{

    $data = $this->model->getClients();
    print_r($data);
}
```

Comment: Has seteado el máximo a 512Mb y 536870912 bytes son 512 Mb, cual es el error?

Comment: tambien he probado asi **ini_set('memory_limit', '536870912');** pero no ha cambiado nada

Comment: Eso sigue siendo 512Mb... tu problema es que se han agotado los 512Mb que tienes asignados. Según ese error, debes asignar más de 512Mb. Recuerda que para que los cambios tengan efecto necesitas reiniciar el servicio

Comment: @Benito-B he puesto **ini_set('memory_limit', '636870912');** y reiniciado el servidor y no funciona

Comment: Posiblemente estás intentando solucionar el problema incorrecto. Qué estás ejecutando para que no te alcance 1GB de memoria en tu script? Estás cargando todo un archivo en memoria para procesarlo o algo así? Ese puede ser el verdadero problema

Comment: Estoy intentando cargar mi proyecto de mvc en un archivo que me daba error por el nombre del archivo que no me detectaba el archivo y al corregirlo me salio eso, es lo único que te puede decir jajja en esto soy nuevo perdón por ser mas especifico

Comment: Creo que vale la pena que pongas en tu pregunta el escenario completo. Cómo estabas _cargando el proyecto en un archivo_, qué te fallaba por el nombre, etc. Posiblemente haya una forma más eficiente de hacer lo que intentas.

Comment: @Alfabravo ya esta editado, el fallo que de conexion era que habia puesto conexio.php en vez de Conexion.php por que no me detectaba la clase, despues de eso me esta dando el error ese de memoria

Comment: estas haciendo un select * de una tabla. Cuantos registros tiene? no vaya a ser que al ejecutarlo te este intentando leer todo y por eso se desborde la memoria...

Comment: @Jakala ese select siempre lo he ejecutado de forma normal sin mvc y me funciona y la tabla clientes tiene 15 campos

Comment: 15 campos, pero cuántos registros?

Answer (score 0):

En este caso el problema es obtener un gran dataset totalmente en memoria, que puede agotar la memoria por completo. Ajustando el limite no soluciona el problema real, ya que a medida que los datos crezcan sera necesario un nuevo aumento del limite.

La solucion completa puede ser mas complicada, pero parte ajustando el comportamiento de PDO fetch. Al inicializar PDO se debe incluir el atributo **MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY**, para permitir que las extracciones de datos se hagan en buffer (no todo de una vez, sino a medida que se necesita).

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1', 'user', 'pass', array(
    // atributos de inicializacion
));
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, false);
```

Luego de eso, se debe tener cuidado de ***no usar el dataset completo de una vez***, por ejemplo

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM clientes');
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Puede obligar a obtener y acumular el dataset entero para mostrarlo en la salida. En vez de esto, se debe recorrer el dataset usando fetch():

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM clientes');
$stmt->execute();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

Usando MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY este codigo no consumira mas memoria de lo que se necesita para ejecutar un ciclo del while. Pero si los datos son acumulados de alguna manera se terminara acabando la memoria.

Por tanto lo recomendable es no retornar todos los datos en el modelo, sino solo el result para ser recorrido (como `$stmt`) u obtener los datos en paginas, con LIMIT.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php